# How to download a pdf file from a php powered website with URL of kind http://myurl.com/file.php/...../requireddownload.pdf

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview, android-webservice

I have tried out many ways like using async task and default download manager, but, I ended with downloading a file (I believe that it is downloading file. php  instead of the requireddownload.pdf file), which is not the required file. However the name and extension of downloaded file is the requrieddownload.pdf.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First step declaring persmissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Create a downloader class

```
public class Downloader {

    public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
        try {

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Finally creating an activity which downloads the PDF file from internet,

```
public class PDFFromServerActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "pdf");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Downloader.DownloadFile("http://www.nmu.ac.in/ejournals/aspx/courselist.pdf", file);

        showPdf();
    }
    public void showPdf()
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pdf/Read.pdf");
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
            List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```